# Expect not exiting non-zero

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

My real goal is to have a script that will run locally to ssh into a remote server, restart tomcat, and use `expect` to wait for the "Server startup in" message, or exit non-zero if it sees startup failed. My attempt is this script. I'm using localhost for debugging, and INFO instead of "startup failed" to artificially trigger the exit:

```sh
ssh -T localhost <<SSH_EOF
docker restart app
expect <<EXPECT_EOF
set timeout 30
spawn docker logs --since 1s -f app
expect_before "INFO" { exit 1 }
expect "Server startup in"
EXPECT_EOF
if [[ $? -eq 0]]; then
    echo "Success!"
else
    echo "Failed!"
fi
SSH_EOF
```

The script does exit on the first INFO message, but prints Success! Why wouldn't it exit with 1?

Comment: use `expect -d` to show verbose logging: which is seen first, "INFO" or "Server startup in", I wonder...

Comment: I had tried the `-d` flag, but it's still a great tip. INFO is definitely seen first. The very first line of output is `26-Jan-2019 17:51:32.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.14` and expect would exit immediately, just with `$?` already resolved (see accepted answer) to '0'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `<<` to include a *here document*, which is *subject to  parameter
expansion,  command substitution, and arithmetic expansion*. In particular, the `$?` gets retplaced by 0 (probably) before it is even passed to ssh.

You need to quote the here delimiter to avoid this, eg `<<'SSH_EOF'`. The actual delimeter is still `SSH_EOF`. You should probably do the same for the expect `EXPECT_EOF`, in case of future changes that involve `$`.

Comment: Brilliant. Adding quotes worked perfectly. Thanks!